# Azure Cosmos DB connection in Android?

Tags: android, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to use Azure Cosmos Java-based libraries for connecting my Android app to Cosmos and getting errors.  I am simply doing:

```
CosmosClient client = new CosmosClientBuilder()
                .endpoint("https://mystuff.documents.azure.com:443/")
                .key("MY_KEY")
                .preferredRegions(Collections.singletonList("West US"))
                .consistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.EVENTUAL)
                .contentResponseOnWriteEnabled(true)
                .buildClient();
```

but I get exceptions like:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean;
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.cpu.CpuReader.<init>(CpuReader.java:25)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.cpu.CpuMonitor.<clinit>(CpuMonitor.java:35)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.cpu.CpuMonitor.register(CpuMonitor.java:70)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.<init>(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:263)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.<init>(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:159)
    at com.azure.cosmos.implementation.RxDocumentClientImpl.<init>(RxDocumentClientImpl.java:144)
```

This seems to me to be due to the fact that Android isn't using Sun / Oracle Java but something else.

Anyone found a good way around this?  Besides ditching Microsoft's stuff for something more Android-friendly?

Comment: Obligatory comment that clients should probably never have a DB key. Why not put up at least minimal API intermediary with proper auth endpoints?

Comment: I am facing the same problem , did you find the solution ?